# Perform a User Lockout via APEX Test Class?

Tags: unit-test, community, controller, user

Is there any way to perform a User lockout via an Apex Test Class?

I have a self-service account Unlock feature in my community portal. I'm writing a test class for the Controller - but to ensure that all steps get tested and I manage to achieve 100% code coverage, **I need a user who has been locked out** due to multiple bad password attempts.

I tried using the `LoginController` and submitted the username and a bad password thrice via Apex, but that doesn't seem to trigger the `IsPasswordLocked` field in `UserLogin` object for some reason. The lockout works when I do the same via the UI - but just won't happen via Apex.

I can't set the IsPasswordLocked field to be true via DML update either.

Any suggestions for achieving the same?

Comment: You may already know that IsPasswordLocked field (from UserLogin object) can be set to false, but not true (via apex/ SOQL). It sounds like you apex code is related to unlock functionality only. In your code, why not utilize the User ID that was locked out via UI attempts?

Comment: Hi Arut - thanks for your reply. Yes - I've encountered that issue with isPasswordLocked and thus my question. I'm not able to "force" a user to be locked-out and this is causing certain branches of the code to not run during the unit tests, leading to lower code coverage. In the unit test class, I even attempted to simulate a bad login 5 consecutive times, hoping that this would cause user lockout - but for some reason this doesn't work. In UI, of course, this works fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: To my knowledge, I'm not aware of a code based method to lockout a user (although, I need to check if there is any alternate solution). Why not follow this pattern (may be my earlier comment was not clear)? Lock a user thru bad login attempts via UI -> Fetch this user ID and store it in custom setting -> In your test method, query the user account based on this ID (from custom setting) and run as this user.

Comment: Thank you arut. I'm leaning more and more towards the approach you suggested, in lack of any better alternatives. :D